# How to use Jquery's :not selector on a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an ul list similar to this:

```
<ul>
 <li class="category">Category 1
    <ul>
       <li class="product alpha_a">A Product</li>
       <li class="product alpha_b">B product</li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>
 <li class="category">Category 2
    <ul>
       <li class="product alpha_a">Another Product</li>
       <li class="product alpha_c">c product</li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

what I am trying to do is hide the li elements that are not of a selected alpha class. I have tried this (simplified here):

```
$(".alpha_a").addClass("alphaselected");
$(".product li:not(.alphaselected)").hide();
```

but it doesn't work. I have also tried (among many others):

```
$("#sitemap li:not(.alphaselected,.category)").hide();
```

which seems to hide everything.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The correct selector should be `li.product:not(.alphaselected)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".alpha_a").addClass("alphaselected");
$(".product:not(.alphaselected)").hide();
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nFpqS/)

Comment: There should be no space between `$(".product :not(.alphaselected)"`

Answer (score 2):

it should be - the `product` class belongs to the `li` element so your descendant selector will not return any element

```
$("li.product:not(.alphaselected)").hide();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6825z/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(".alpha_a").addClass("alphaselected");
$("li.product:not(.alphaselected)").hide();
```